# Website presents (not accessible) with internal IP

Tags: dns, webserver

I am in the process (almost done) of migrating a website from an on-prem server onto a server in the cloud.
When I type in the URL, a response comes back "this site can't be reached", and the URL has changed from the subdoman/domain name I entered into the browser to the *correct* path, but with the *internal* IP instead of the domain name.

When I then change this again (to https://subdomain.domain.tld/), the site that I wanted to visit pops up.

I am suspecting some error in a setting on the server, but I don't know exactly where to look.

I have set up a virtual host file for the site, and there I have configured
**<VirtualHost [internal IP address]:443>
ServerName [fully qualified domain name]**

When I change the  entry so it says <VirtualHost [fully qualified domain name]:443>, I get an error **ERR_BAD_SSL_CLIENT_AUTH_CERT**

The fact that the certificate is accepted when I try a second time with the internal IP in the virtual host file tells me there's not really anything wrong with the certificate.

Where else can I look?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: are you using virtualhosts?

Comment: I am using virtualhosts. I've edited the question to elaborate on that.

Answer (score 0):

I've resolved the issue...
The application I am hosting is a mediawiki.
Mediawiki has a variable "$wgServer", which also needs to point to the FQDN...
After setting that, all is well.

What did I do to find this "bug"?
I looked for the internal IP in all possible paths in Linux
First /etc/, which gave me /etc/httpd/conf.d/
Then /var/www/, where the application is located. There I found it in /var/www/mediawiki-1.39.0/LocalSettings.php.

Thanks for the temporary use of your braincells. ;)